# Compare enum with list Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have an enum inserted in an entity, with some default values. I want to compare this with the enums assigned to the entity.

I tried looking for the enum string in the list, but I don't get a result

```java
public class Role{

@NotEmpty
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private Authority authority;

public static enum Authority {
        ROLE_ADMIN,
        ROLE_USER
    }
}
```

```java
public class UserCheck implements UserDetails {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private List<Role> roles;

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
}
```

the enum is traversed and compared to the list

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleSelectStore">Roles</label> <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelectStore"  multiple="multiple">
<option th:each="authority : ${T(cl.tricotcorp.app.checklist.models.entity.Role.Authority).values()}"                           th:text="${authority}" th:value="${authority}" th:selected="${#lists.contains(userCheck.getRoles(), authority)}">                               </select>
</div>
```

the expected result is to mark the matches as "checked"

Answer (score 2):

`getRoles()` returns a `List<Role>`, and `authority` is an `Authority`, so you're basically asking if any `Role.equals(Authority)`, which by definition is always `false`.

One way to fix it, so its easy to use, is to add a helper method to `UserCheck`:

```java
public boolean hasAuthority(Authority authority) {
    return this.roles.stream().anyMatch(r -> r.getAuthority() == authority);
}
```

Then your Thymeleaf code would be:

```html
<option ... th:selected="${userCheck.hasAuthority(authority)}">
```